# How bad is to make frequent allocations, if we're talking on small objects?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, wrapper, allocation

For example there are poco class:

```
class Foo{/*code*/}
```

and decorator class

```
class FooWrapper 
{

    public FooWrapper (Foo wrapped)
    {
        Wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public Foo Wrapped{get;} 
    /*Decorating Methods*/
}
```

which has just one auto property only and a plenty of decorating methods. So, allocated objects are really small and contain only one reference.
How badly frequent allocations of FooWrapper e.g.

```
List<FooWrapper> GetListOfWrappedFoo(List<Foo> list) 
                          => list.Select(it => new FooWrapper(it)).ToList();
```

can affect efficiency?

I've tried to find an answer on different resourses, but unfortunately I've failed.

Comment: You can use a profiler to find out how often your code triggers garbage collection. Allocation itself is generally rather inexpensive, but collections can be an issue if you trigger them too often

Comment: You probably need to see for yourself, that is: run your horses. And the best thing to do that with is probably [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/).